# Data source filter in Power BI for loading Azure Databricks table

Tags: powerquery, datasource, azure-databricks, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am loading a table from Azure DataBricks into Power Bi desktop. Now the problem is the data is so huge that it takes 25 minutes to load. I want to filter the data on the date basis so that only latest data is imported.

How do I do that? I can see that after loading I can add a step to filter the date but the loading itself is taking a lot of time. I want to load only the relevant data (i.e  the latest Date).

Please help.

Just like when we load a data set from SQL Server. We have an option to write SQL query to load the data when we select Advance Option(this helps to filter the data at the even before importing). But the same thing is not available while loading data from Azure Databricks.

Comment: Even while loading data from azure databricks there is option to write sql query. Go to 
advance option give catalog name and query.

Answer (score 1):

To filter the data on the date basis before importing it into Power BI Desktop, you can use the **Query Options** feature in the **Get Data** window. Below are the steps:

- In Power BI Desktop, click on "Get Data" in the Home ribbon.
- Select "Azure" from the list of data sources and then select "Azure Databricks".

[image]

- Give the server host name and HTTP path and then expand "Advanced options".
- Give the catalog name and enter a SQL query to filter the data based on the date.
  For example, if you want to import only the data for the last 7 days, you can use the following query:

```
 SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <date_column> >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

[image]

- Click on `OK`
- Click on `Load`.

This should help you to import only the relevant data.

Comment: Hi, Even after providing Catalog, I do not see Native query option in my connector window

Comment: Could you share the screenshot

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltvy0.png

Comment: Okay, I know why it is not visible. It is because the Power Bi version I am using is Old. It is available in new versions. Also, I have 1 more question, Can I pass Parameter value in the Native SQL query??

Comment: I think it is not possible to filter dynamically.

Comment: So if I want to get only the latest date Data, then using Native Query will not help me right? What would be the best approach in this case?

Comment: Why do you need to pass parameter value to get the latest date Data?